# setting values at child views in linear layout

Tags: java, android

I have template of linear layout which has two text fields to hold question number and questions.
This template is used in master activity by using include tag multiple times. 
I was trying to set the question numbers in this master view based on the count of child views it has, but only last iterations of loop gets updated . example, If there are 3 child views, the first question will have question number set to 3, others are not impacted at all. Relevant codes are as below.

Master Activity:

```
<LinearLayout ...
     android:id="@+id/id_activity_main" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/inc_id_1"
        layout="@layout/template" />

     <include
        android:id="@+id/inc_id_2"
        layout="@layout/template" />

     <include
        android:id="@+id/inc_id_3"
        layout="@layout/template" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Template layout:

```
 <LinearLayout ... >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_q_number"
       ....../>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_question"
        ..... />

</LinearLayout>
```

and in my activity for master (I think I have done some stupidity in this loop but too blind to see it ) :

```
LinearLayout masterLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.id_activity_main);
int childCount=masterLayout.getChildCount();
for(int i=0;i<childCount;i++){

    //individual embedded template 
    LinearLayout linearRowView=(LinearLayout) masterLayout.getChildAt(0); 

    //fetchin question number text field for each embedded template
    TextView questionNumberTextView=(TextView) linearRowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_q_number);

    //setting question number in each question number field of included template
    questionNumberTextView.setText(i+1+"");
}
```

In above example, when I leave default text for question number text view as 1, the out put would be :

```
3.   first questions text.
1.   second  question text.
1.   third question text.
```

My question is , why its not updated as 1,2,3 but updated as 3,1,1. ( 1 is default). Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `i` instead of 0, in the following

```
LinearLayout linearRowView=(LinearLayout) masterLayout.getChildAt(i);
```